# MySQL connection works on Localhost but not on webserver

Tags: php, mysql

Good day Everyone..

I have an issue that is puzzling me and I can not seem to find a way to solve it. Even the tech support in my hosting service can not solve it.

I have created a small script to do a simple task. I require the employees to log in to perform any said task.

I have tested the application on a development server and the login script works perfectly, but when I place it on the webserver the connection is never established.

I use the same username and passowrd in the dbcon.php file to log in using phpMyAdmin and it works, and I run the queries and they also work.

Here are the files:

1: dbcon.php

```
<?php
$connect = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mdchaara_draiwil_dms;charset=utf8";
$db_user = "dbusername";
$db_pass = "dbpassword";

$db = new PDO($connect,$db_user,$db_pass);
?>
```

2: login.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require "../../_dbcon/_dbcon.php";
//Timezone settings:
$timezone = "Asia/Kuwait";
                if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

// check the username has only alpha numeric characters
if (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
    //if there is no match
    $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
//check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
if (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
{
    //if there is no match ***/
    $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
    // if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    //SQL Injection Precaution:/
    $username   =   stripslashes($username);
    $password   =   stripslashes($password);


   try
    {


        //Select Statement:
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * 
                            FROM dms_gt_users 
                            WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
        some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
    }

    // If result matched $username and $password, there will be one row
    if($result==1){
        // check if the account is active:

        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id_status 
                            FROM dms_gt_users 
                            WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $id_status=  $row['id_status'];
                    } 

        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT employee_id 
                            FROM dms_gt_users 
                            WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $employee_id=  $row['employee_id'];
                    } 

        //Check if account is active:
        if($id_status == "A"){

            // Create Session ID:
            $session_id = "";
            $_SESSION['sid'] = "";

            $session_id = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
            $sid_update = $db->query("UPDATE    dms_gt_users 
                                SET `session_id`='$session_id'
                                WHERE username='$username' and password ='$password'");

            $_SESSION['sid']    =   $session_id;

            //Get last login details:
            $current_login = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT `last_log_in`
                                FROM dms_gt_users 
                                WHERE `employee_id` = '.$employee_id);

                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $last_log_in = $row['last_log_in'];
                }   

                $_SESSION['last_log_in'] = $last_log_in;

            //get IP address:
            $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

            //Add login details to Activity Log:
            $stmt = $db->query("INSERT INTO dms_activity_log
                     (`employee_id`, `activity_date_time`, `activity`, `ip_address`) 
                     VALUES ('$employee_id', '$current_login', 'Logged in', '$ip')");

            //Add login details to users table:
            $stmt = $db->query("UPDATE  dms_gt_users 
                                SET `last_log_in`='$current_login'
                            WHERE username='$username' and password ='$password'");

            //update session login
            $_SESSION['login']= 1;

            //save employee id to session
            $_SESSION['employee_id'] = $employee_id;

            // redirect to portal home:
                header ("Location:../../../home.php");
            }

        //Account is not Active:
        else{
            header ("Location:../../../index.php");
        }
    }

    //Username or password are incorrect
    else {
            header ("Location:../../../index.php");
    }
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? and if my code is ok, what should I tell the hosting Tech Support to look for?

Thanks!!

*EDIT*

@noc2spam: I have updated the connection string as you have advised, I get no errors logged. I var_dump the $db, and I get `object(PDO)#1 (0)`

Comment: you use PDO. Please use prepared statements with placeholders to avoid sql injection.

Comment: When in development, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: You've got a massive security problem here due to a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_POST` data **never** goes into a query without escaping. As @vmai says, PDO has placeholders that are [easy to use](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059).

Comment: I'm aware of the SQL injection issue, I simplified the code to get to the root of the problem. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Did you integrate your sql injection problem by simplifying your code? At which point do you have a problem? You've got successfully created an PDO object. So what now?

Comment: @VMai: PDO object is not even created. that is the problem. The connection is never established. When the login form is submitted, the login.php file always returns 'Could not get username and password from db'. the actual code is edited above.

Comment: var_dump() isn't very talkative about PDO-objects :-( You should try to create your PDO instance with as Fred -ii- and noc2spam said and catch the error message.

Comment: Your SQL injection protection is insufficient and can be bypassed easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty hard to tell why this is happening without looking into the server itself. I suggest that you enable the Exception mode so that you can see what the problem is. For example:

```
try {
   $connect = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mdchaara_draiwil_dms;charset=utf8";
   $db_user = "dbusername";
   $db_pass = "dbpassword";

  $db = new PDO($connect,$db_user,$db_pass);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

It would be much easier to troubleshoot now. Check if you are getting any error and update the original question with the message if possible. I will edit this answer after that.

Answer (score 2):

IF Roger Ng's answer doesn't solve it, then you may have a firewall blocking your connection.  Check your mysql server port... typically 3306.

Comment: after struggle for 6 hours its worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Check your database's url. Generally, in shared/dedicated hosting environment, DB server and App Server are on different machines. Also, many service providers do not provide mysql cluster services on port 3306. So, please get the correct URL and port of the database from your hosts CPanel or tech support team.

Also, add the App server's IP address to the permitted IP addresses list in `Remote MySQL` Cpanel interface.